# Ruby on Rails: rails generate migration is not giving me a new migration, but giving me an app called generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I typed this into terminal:

```
rails generate migration CreateAddress
```

and instead of creating a new migration file, it created the entirety of a naked rails app.

What is wrong here?

Comment: In Rails 3.0 and above, all the scripts in the `scripts` directory have been consolidated into a single `rails` script. So your command is correct for Rails 3 applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `generate` script is a Ruby script, so you should just call it with `ruby`.

Also, you usually want to call that script from the top level of your app, so:

```
$ ruby script/generate migration CreateAddress
```

The reason you have your issue is because executing `rails` simply creates a naked Rails app in your current directory with the first argument as its name. In this case, that's obviously "generate".

Comment: As mentioned above, the syntax depends on Rails version.